# Add two lines below text

Tags: html, css

I want to add two lines below my `p` tag, But I want the lines to take 100% width of the container.
How can I achieve this? I can't use hr tags, it should be done with CSS `pseudo classes` I guess.

**CSS AND HTML CODE:**

```css
.test {
  max-width: 320px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<p>Test</p>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: you can use pesudo elements "after"," before" on container class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.test {
  max-width: 320px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 4px double black;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-align:center` to center your text.
Use `border-bottom` instead of `border` to make your border appear only below.

Then use a `:after` element to generate the second border.

To make your element take 100% of its container, just remove the `max-width`. As its a div (which is a block-level element) it will automatically take 100% of its parent space if you dont tell it otherwise.

```css
.test {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.test:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change property `border` to `border-bottom` and set the border style to `double`

```css
.test {
  max-width: 320px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 6px double #444;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach. I hope is helpful to you. You have the flexibility to adjust the space between lines with `margin-bottom: 2px;`

```css
.test {
  max-width: 320px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;  
  text-align:center;
}
.test p {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;  
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the "border-bottom" style property can help to draw lines below an element. You can use below code :

```
.test {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: double;
  text-align: center;
}

<div class="test">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `::before` and `::after` to achieve this style.

```css
.test {
  max-width: 320px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.text::before,
.text::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

.text::after {
  bottom: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p class="text">Test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: also, this does not depend on the `div` tag